# How to not get error prompting canvas is null

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a canvas where a box will appear and I am able to drag its corners to the desired position. The problem is when I run the page, it gives an error "canvas is null". I am not sure how do i solve the issue.

```
 <script>
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
                    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
                    rect = {
                        x: 150,
                        y: 100,
                        w: 123,
                        h: 58
                    },
            handlesSize = 8,
                    currentHandle = false,
                    drag = false;

            function init() {
                canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
                canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
                canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
            }

            function point(x, y) {
                return {
                    x: x,
                    y: y
                };
            }

            function dist(p1, p2) {
                return Math.sqrt((p2.x - p1.x) * (p2.x - p1.x) + (p2.y - p1.y) * (p2.y - p1.y));
            }

            function getHandle(mouse) {
                if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x, rect.y)) <= handlesSize)
                    return 'topleft';
                if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x + rect.w, rect.y)) <= handlesSize)
                    return 'topright';
                if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x, rect.y + rect.h)) <= handlesSize)
                    return 'bottomleft';
                if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x + rect.w, rect.y + rect.h)) <= handlesSize)
                    return 'bottomright';
                if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x + rect.w / 2, rect.y)) <= handlesSize)
                    return 'top';
                if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x, rect.y + rect.h / 2)) <= handlesSize)
                    return 'left';
                if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x + rect.w / 2, rect.y + rect.h)) <= handlesSize)
                    return 'bottom';
                if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x + rect.w, rect.y + rect.h / 2)) <= handlesSize)
                    return 'right';
                return false;
            }

            function mouseDown(e) {
                if (currentHandle)
                    drag = true;
                draw();
            }

            function mouseUp() {
                drag = false;
                currentHandle = false;
                draw();
            }

            function mouseMove(e) {
                var previousHandle = currentHandle;
                if (!drag)
                    currentHandle = getHandle(point(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop));
                if (currentHandle && drag) {
                    var mousePos = point(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
                    switch (currentHandle) {
                        case 'topleft':
                            rect.w += rect.x - mousePos.x;
                            rect.h += rect.y - mousePos.y;
                            rect.x = mousePos.x;
                            rect.y = mousePos.y;
                            break;
                        case 'topright':
                            rect.w = mousePos.x - rect.x;
                            rect.h += rect.y - mousePos.y;
                            rect.y = mousePos.y;
                            break;
                        case 'bottomleft':
                            rect.w += rect.x - mousePos.x;
                            rect.x = mousePos.x;
                            rect.h = mousePos.y - rect.y;
                            break;
                        case 'bottomright':
                            rect.w = mousePos.x - rect.x;
                            rect.h = mousePos.y - rect.y;
                            break;

                        case 'top':
                            rect.h += rect.y - mousePos.y;
                            rect.y = mousePos.y;
                            break;

                        case 'left':
                            rect.w += rect.x - mousePos.x;
                            rect.x = mousePos.x;
                            break;

                        case 'bottom':
                            rect.h = mousePos.y - rect.y;
                            break;

                        case 'right':
                            rect.w = mousePos.x - rect.x;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                if (drag || currentHandle != previousHandle)
                    draw();
            }

            function draw() {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
                ctx.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.w, rect.h);
                if (currentHandle) {
                    var posHandle = point(0, 0);
                    switch (currentHandle) {
                        case 'topleft':
                            posHandle.x = rect.x;
                            posHandle.y = rect.y;
                            break;
                        case 'topright':
                            posHandle.x = rect.x + rect.w;
                            posHandle.y = rect.y;
                            break;
                        case 'bottomleft':
                            posHandle.x = rect.x;
                            posHandle.y = rect.y + rect.h;
                            break;
                        case 'bottomright':
                            posHandle.x = rect.x + rect.w;
                            posHandle.y = rect.y + rect.h;
                            break;
                        case 'top':
                            posHandle.x = rect.x + rect.w / 2;
                            posHandle.y = rect.y;
                            break;
                        case 'left':
                            posHandle.x = rect.x;
                            posHandle.y = rect.y + rect.h / 2;
                            break;
                        case 'bottom':
                            posHandle.x = rect.x + rect.w / 2;
                            posHandle.y = rect.y + rect.h;
                            break;
                        case 'right':
                            posHandle.x = rect.x + rect.w;
                            posHandle.y = rect.y + rect.h / 2;
                            break;
                    }
                    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'xor';
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(posHandle.x, posHandle.y, handlesSize, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                    ctx.fill();
                    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
                }
            }

            init();
            draw();
        </script>


 <body>

        <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>

    </body>
```

Comment: When I copy and paste your code it works fine, I am assuming you are running the JS before you have made the canvas in the html, is your script in the head of the page or at the bottom?
If you are running the script before the browser has read the DOM, it will return null for the canvas as it doesn't exist at that point.

Comment: My script is between the head tag, before the body tag

Comment: Put the script within the body tag, but after the <canvas></canvas> tag.
Your script is being run before the browser has had a chance to find the <canvas> you are referencing, so it doesn't exist.

Comment: You have to wait until the page (including the canvas) is loaded. Now you're probably requesting a canvas that doesn't exist yet. Read more at https://flaviocopes.com/dom-ready/